# Repercussions of adding "Removed" state to Azure DevOps Bugs in Agile process

Tags: azure-devops

In Azure DevOps, the Bug WIT state workflow includes the Removed state in the Scrum process but not in the Agile process.

We would like to add the Removed state to our Agile process Bug WIT. We understand how to do so, but the fact that it's different gives us pause. ADO typically has good reason for the base configuration, so it would be helpful to know why the difference exists, as well as any info on potential repercussions of adding the Removed state to the Agile Bug WIT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This is not a problem in Azure DevOps but the standard process
>   (**[Agile workflow states](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/work-items/guidance/agile-process-workflow?view=azure-devops#agile-workflow-states)**). The following are the steps that can
>   be used for the workflow in the standard process:
>
> - **User Story** (New, Active, Removed, Resolved, Closed)
> - **Bug** (New, Active, Resolved, Closed)
> - **Task** (New, Active, Removed, Closed)

[image]

In Azure DevOps, however, this workflow can be adapted. For this the process must be modified. Here you can also add **Removed** for a bug type within the workflow.

You can use the Removed state as long as it works for you. You'll be able to update your work items you've set to Removed to another state, or simply do a Bulk delete.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you. I understand all of that. Just wanted to be cautious before changing a canned workflow.

Comment: Thanks for your kindly response. Good to know you are cautious about this. It's safe to do this. You can set a limitation such as user story/task, only change bug state to Removed when the task state is New (Agile). There is nothing special mention notice.